# Using QueryDSL in order to query a database for close distance points

Tags: geolocation, querydsl

I have the following entities in my application:

- `Member`
- `FamilyAdvertisment`
- `Address`

In `Member` entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "member")
private List<Advertisement> advertisements;
```

In `Advertisement` entity:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Member member;
```

Full `Address` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    private String formattedAddress;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
}
```

**I am trying to find all those FamilyAdvertisement instances whose member has an adress within 20KM of the required address.**

Here is what I have come up with:

```
QFamilyAdvertisement qFamilyAdvertisement = QFamilyAdvertisement.familyAdvertisement;

NumberPath<Double> lat = qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address.latitude;//NPE
NumberPath<Double> lng = qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address.longitude;
NumberPath<Double> distance = null;
NumberExpression<Double> formula = 
        (acos(cos(radians(Expressions.constant(requiredAddress.getLatitude())))
        .multiply(cos(radians(lat))
        .multiply(cos(radians(lng).subtract(radians(Expressions.constant(requiredAddress.getLongitude())))
        .add(sin(radians(Expressions.constant(requiredAddress.getLatitude())))
        .multiply(sin(radians(lat))))))))
        .multiply(Expressions.constant(6371)));

List<FamilyAdvertisement> foundFamilyAdvertisements = from(qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address).where(formula.as(distance).lt(20)).list(qFamilyAdvertisement);
```

However, it seems that I am incorrectly using the NumberPath class as I keep getting a NPE. Can anyone please help me get my query right?

**edit**: I have altered my FamilyAdvertisement entity as follows:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@QueryInit("address")
private Member member;
```

I now get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only root paths are allowed for joins : familyAdvertisement.member.address
    com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.ensureRoot(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:208)
    com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.validateJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:132)
    com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.addJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:118)
    com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.addJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:110)
    com.mysema.query.support.QueryMixin.from(QueryMixin.java:161)
    com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLQueryBase.from(JPQLQueryBase.java:96)
    com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.from(JPAQuery.java:30)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.Querydsl.createQuery(Querydsl.java:88)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslRepositorySupport.from(QueryDslRepositorySupport.java:94)
    com.bignibou.repository.FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryImpl.performFamilyAdvertisementSearch(FamilyAdvertisementRepositoryImpl.java:64)
```

Line 64 is this one:

```
List<FamilyAdvertisement> foundFamilyAdvertisements = from(qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address).where(formula.as(distance).lt(20)).list(qFamilyAdvertisement);
```

Any clue what is wrong now?

**edit2**: I forgot to mention that `FamilyAdvertisement` extends `Advertisement` and that the `member` variable is in `Advertisement`.

**edit3**: Here is the SQL I am trying to reproduce with QueryDSL:

```
select * from family_advertisement a inner join member m
on a.member = m.id
where m.address
in (
SELECT id 
FROM address where 
 6371 * 
acos( cos( radians(48.8558966) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(2.3622728) ) 
+ sin( radians(48.8558966) )
* sin( radians( latitude ) )
) < 20);
```

I have tried something like this:

```
List<FamilyAdvertisement> foundFamilyAdvertisements = from(qFamilyAdvertisement).where(qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address.in(

                new JPASubQuery().from(QAddress.address).where(formula.lt(20)))

                ).list(qFamilyAdvertisement);
```

where formula is given above but I am not sure how to express a noncorrelated subquery in QueryDSL and especially the in operator above seems to be problematical...

**edit4**:

The following subquery now works:

```
List<FamilyAdvertisement> foundFamilyAdvertisements = 
        from(qFamilyAdvertisement).where(qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address.in(new JPASubQuery().from(QAddress.address).where(formula.lt(20)).list(QAddress.address))).list(qFamilyAdvertisement);
```

Comment: I tried out your method, and even created addresses with the same gps.
Yet, nothing was being returned as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path is too long for eager initialization

```
qFamilyAdvertisement.member.address.latitude;
```

Please read here more about path initialization in Querydsl http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.0/reference/html/ch03s04.html#d0e1699

Comment: Hi Timo. I have modified my entity and I now get a: `IllegalArgumentException: Only root paths are allowed for joins : familyAdvertisement.member.address`. I have edited my post.

Comment: The from argument needs to be a root path, a variable.

Comment: I am trying to use a subquery but the `in` method won't take a subquery as in sql. Any idea how to get this right Timo?